# How to convert string to edit text box in android in intent?

Tags: android, kotlin

How to convert a string to EditText , i make a EditText in one activity and then make a second activity and i get this edittext through the intent in the string then
how to assign it to the second activity's edittext , but i don't find it how to assign string to edittext.Here i used a go function that is used when onclick event is occured of button

```
This is my first activity

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() , View.OnClickListener{ 
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
    fun go(v:View){
        val intent=Intent(this@MainActivity,Main2Activity::class.java)
        var aa=EditText1.text
        intent.putExtra("name",aa)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}

This is my second activity

class Main2Activity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)
        var str=intent.getStringExtra("name").toString()
        et21.setText(str)
    }
}
```

Comment: Here when i run this , my application is crashed

Comment: Where did you initialize `et21`?

Comment: this is my main activity
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="enter name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnlink"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="go"
        android:text="go to..." />

Comment: this is my main activity2
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et21"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
        />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)
    val extras:Bundle =intent.extras
    val nn=extras.getString("name")
    eT21.setText("${nn}")
}

Or

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)
    eT21.setText(intent.getStringExtra("name"))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Its because you was trying to set `charSequence` to your `EditText` , just convert to `String` while getting value from `FirstEditText`.

inside your Second Activity -

```
  class Main2Activity : AppCompatActivity() {
                override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)
                    intent.getStringExtra("name")?.let {
                     et21.setText(it)
                    }
                }
            }
```

Inside your first activity

```
fun go(v:View){
        val intent=Intent(this@MainActivity,Main2Activity::class.java)
        var aa=EditText1.text.toString()
        intent.putExtra("name",aa)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

Comment: updated the answer it runs  , take this above code and let me know

Comment: still it gives me that unfortunetoly stop the app

Comment: @Thunder the design of the let block for nullable types in kotlin is such that you will automatically get the non nullable value inside let block is that nullable has some value. And which can be accessed using "it" keyword. For me it does not make sense to call intent.getStringExtra("name") again inside the let block. Check https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/idioms.html#map-nullable-value-if-not-null

Comment: inside your first activity add .toString 

var aa=EditText1.text.toString()

Answer (score 1):

In your first activity change go function as below,

```
 fun go(v:View){
        val intent=Intent(this@MainActivity,Main2Activity::class.java)
        var aa=EditText1.text.toString()
        intent.putExtra("name",aa)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

In your second activity change the last line of onCreate as below, you need to unwrap the value from an nullable type. Which can be done using let block over nullable type. Also I am assuming et21 is reference to the edit text and is properly initialised.
This solution is null safe

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)
    intent.getStringExtra("name")?.let {
        et21.setText(it)
    }
}
```

Comment: @Thunder bro,here i go to the second activity but i can't get a data in second activity in edittext in et21

Comment: @hardikgosai please check the edited answer. You need change go func as well. please let me know if it works,